# How would you go about finding the latest date in a dataframe groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to create a sub-table from a larger dataset which lists out the unique ID, the name of the person and the date they attended an appointment.

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['abc', 'def', 'abc', 'abc'], 
                   'name':['Alex','Bertie','Alex','Alex'],
                   'date_attended':['01/01/2021','05/01/2021','11/01/2021','20/01/2021']
```

What I would like is a dataframe, that shows the last time Alex and Bertie attended a class. So my dataframe would like:

```
name      date_attended
Alex      20/01/2021
Bertie    05/01/2021
```

I'm really struggling with this! So far I have tried (based off a previous question I saw here):

```
max_date_list = ['ID','date_attended']
df = df.groupby(['ID'])[max_date_list].transform('max').size()
```

but I keep getting an error. I know this would involve a `groupby` but I can't figure out how to get the maximum date. Would anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: does `df.groupby(['ID', 'name'])['date_attended'].max()` not work?

Comment: The error I am getting is :numpy.int64 is not instance of int.

Comment: Ensure 'date_attended' is datetime dtype and not string.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the type date_attended was and the other suggestions worked! Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sort_values` by 'date_attended' and `drop_duplicates` by 'ID':

```
df['date_attended'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_attended'], dayfirst=True)     
df.sort_values('date_attended', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('ID')
```

Output:

```
    ID    name date_attended
3  abc    Alex    2021-01-20
1  def  Bertie    2021-01-05
```

Answer (score 1):

To match your expected output format exactly, you might want to `groupby` "name":

```
>>> df.groupby("name")["date_attended"].max()
name
Alex      20/01/2021
Bertie    05/01/2021
Name: date_attended, dtype: object
```

Alternatively, if you might have different ID with the same name:

```
>>> df.groupby("ID").agg({"name": "first", "date_attended": "max"}).set_index("name")
       date_attended
name                
Alex      20/01/2021
Bertie    05/01/2021
```